# Can I merge two .NET DataTables, without merging null values, without having to loop through the rows myself?

Tags: .net

Suppose I have two .NET DataTables populated as follows, where ID is the primary key, and where `null` means a `DBNull.Value` (not the string `"null"`):

```
    |Table A                |           |Table B
    |ID   |Column1 |Column2 |           |ID   |Column1 |Column2 |
    |1    |foo     |10      |           |1    |zzz     |null    |
    |2    |baz     |20      |           |2    |null    |99      |
```

I want to do a merge of these tables, where the result will be:

```
    |ID   |Column1 |Column2 |
    |1    |zzz     |10      |
    |2    |baz     |99      |
```

In other words, I want to merge the data from Table B into Table A, just like `DataTable.Merge` does, but instead of copying the entire row from table B when the IDs match, I only want to copy the fields where the data is not null.

I could write my own loops through the rows of both tables to do this, but I'm wondering if there is already a method in the libraries, so that I don't have to rewrite my own version of `DataTable.Merge`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rats...I don't think what I'm looking for exists.

For what it's worth, if anyone looking at this has the same need as I did, this is the "roll my own" code that I ended up with:

```
        // Merge 
        foreach (DataRow br in tableB.Rows)
        {
            // This assumes a one-column primary key. In my case,
            // that's valid, but not for a general-purpose function.
            DataRow ar = tableA.Rows.Find(br[tableB.PrimaryKey[0]]);
            if (ar == null)
            {
                continue;
                // If I really wanted it to act like DataTable.Merge, it would
                // add the missing row to tableA rather than just skipping it.
                // again, I didn't implement this because I didn't need it.
            }
            foreach (DataColumn ac in tableA.Columns)
            {
                DataColumn bc = tableB.Columns[ac.ColumnName];
                if (bc != null && !br.IsNull(bc))
                    ar[ac] = br[bc];
            }
        }
```

As the comments indicate, this doesn't do all of what DataTable.Merge does, and makes some assumptions that aren't valid in general.  It wouldn't be hard to fix those issues though.  I leave it here in case it helps somebody.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
public static DataTable Union (DataTable First, DataTable Second)
{

      //Result table
      DataTable table = new DataTable("Union");

      //Build new columns
      DataColumn[] newcolumns = new DataColumn[First.Columns.Count];

      for(int i=0; i < First.Columns.Count; i++)
      {
          newcolumns[i] = new DataColumn(
          First.Columns[i].ColumnName, First.Columns[i].DataType);
      }

      table.Columns.AddRange(newcolumns);
      table.BeginLoadData();

      foreach(DataRow row in First.Rows)
      {
           table.LoadDataRow(row.ItemArray,true);
      }

      foreach(DataRow row in Second.Rows)
      {
          table.LoadDataRow(row.ItemArray,true);
      }

      table.EndLoadData();
      return table;
}
```

From [here](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/davidm/archive/2004/01/15/724.aspx) (not tested).

Comment: Nope, that doesn't work...as written, that just adds the rows of the second table at the bottom without updating rows with the same PK (since you haven't added the primary key to the "Union" table).  I tried using LoadDataRow after adding the primary key, but that does the same thing as DataTable.Merge--it updates the entire row with all values from the second table, including the nulls.

I ended up rolling my own...oh well.